# What to do after visiting unsafe site

Tags: firefox, security

I'm sorry if this isn't the place to ask this, but there doesn't seem to be a web security stack exchange site, so this looks like the closest thing to me. If there's a better place to put this question please let me know.

I'm using Firefox on Ubuntu and I accidentally clicked an ad that took me to an obvious scam site. There's no changed behavior on my computer, but just to be safe I'd like to know what you should do after visiting an unsafe site. Thanks

Comment: There is https://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it was a quick access and you immediately left that site, then almost certainly no damage could have been done.

For them to be able to use JS to exploit something on your PC would take much more than just clicking a link.

What could have happened is they could have stolen your cookies, so for safety you can just delete all your cookies and history.

In the future don't just click random links, always make sure where they link to.

Also just be aware, if you notice any sort of random activity on any of your accounts, just immediately react to it.

But you are probably being overly paranoid, it's highly unlikely that anything crucial could have happened just from that.

I'd like to add that if you wanted to protect yourself in the future install uBlock Origin as an addon in your browser, it does much more than just blocking ads and it also prevents most forms of JavaScript and XSS attacks.

If you're using Firefox, which I recommend for your privacy and security, you can also install Multi-account containers, so that you can open different tabs under unique identities, sessions and cookies, so that even if something happened it can't access all of your stuff.

I'd recommend installing those addons if you'd like to go the extra mile.

Comment: Just to add to that, you can afford some protection by installing ClamTK Virus Scanner from the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Ads are one of the worst links to chick on, think almost all websites don't get to check what ads are shown.  One of the reasons adblockers are recommended by most tech sites, even if they use ads.  If something in an ad interest you, be best to go straight to product page, after checking it with a search page.  If browser works funny after, usually just have to remove browser and install it again in linux.

Comment: +1 for the multi account containers. Been using them since forever and they are amazing. Finally I can keep everything separated.